# Getting wrong response from the server when credentials are right at login and getting it when credentials are wrong

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, vite

I'm working on a React login component using Axios to send login requests to my server. Strangely, when I provide the correct credentials, I'm getting an unexpected response from the server, and when I use incorrect credentials, I receive the expected response. Here's my code:

I'm using Vite for my development environment, and here's the Axios code in my handleLogin function:

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const res = await axios.post(`${baseURI}/login`, {
    email: email,
    password: password
  }, {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",         
    }
  });
  const data = res.data;
  console.log(data);
  if(data.user){
    localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
    setUser({
      userEmail: email
    }); 
    navigate('/');
  } else {
    alert("Couldn't log you in");
  }
}
```

upon successful login i should get an object with the users array but getting response without that user array

I tried running this replit same problem and in postman it gives correct response

response I'm getting :

```
 Object { message: "home page GET", admin: false, products: (5) […],     productCategories: (5) […] }
admin: false
message: "home page GET"
productCategories: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
products: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

Response i should get :

````
{
    "message": "home page GET (Logged in User)",
    "title": "User's name",
    "admin": false,
    "user": {
        "_id": "657a16dc84f0dbdec868d644",
        "name": "hidden name",
        "userName": "hiddem username",
        "email": "hiiden email",
        "password": "$2a$10$77KdpdqRC7aOU1iwV9prDOtHJf6VtNJ/RQczOevafsumFg9sXaRu2",
        "phone": "hidden number",
        "joinedOn": "2023-12-13T20:41:00.506Z",
        "blocked": false,
        "age": "21",
        "lastName": "",
        "phoneNumberAlternative": "hidden number",
        "userTagline": "Hello this tag line is updated"
    },
    productCategories: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
products: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]```
````

Comment: what response are you getting? please update with your question. And you should set the user email when you get a response from `data.user.email`.

Comment: One thing to note is that when your property name and passing a value variable name are the same, you can simplify this with {email, password}.

Comment: here is the response I have edited it

Comment: you are not getting a user object from the response. this means your server not returning the user object it omitted. One thing to note here, you must filter the user object when returning as a response because the user object contains `hashed_password`, `phone_number` and so on that are not to be get as a response back.

Comment: How to solve this problem then

Comment: It's from the server so you have to look at the response at the `/login` route and check the SQL query or ORM query from the DB.